# JSON Parse not working, parsing two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to parse this LOCAL XMLhttprequest, I am getting back the right response text and displaying it in safari. 
When I make an object to JSON.parse() the responsetext,I am getting errors like "unidentified token '"' " or "expected '}' " no matter how I change the .txt file, it will not parse into an object for me

I have tried to change the .txt to the right JSON format with no luck

```
{playerGrid: [["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3"], ["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"], ["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3"],["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3"], ["4","2","2","2","2","3","2","2","2","3"], ["2","2","2","2","7","3","2","2","2","3"], ["2","2","2","2","7","2","2","2","2","2"], ["2","2","2","3","3","3","2","2","2","2"], ["2","2","2,"2","2","2","2","2","2","2"], ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"]],
computerGrid: [["2","2","2","7","4","9","9","2","2","2"], ["2","9","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"], ["2","9","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"], ["2","9","2","2","9","9","2","2,"2","2"], ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"], ["9","9","9","9","9","2","2","2","2","2"], ["2","2","2","2","7","2","2","2","9","2"], ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"], ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"], ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"]]};
```

here is my JOSN .txt

```
function fileRequest()
{

  var localRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  localRequest.open("GET", "sampleJSON.txt", false);

  localRequest.send(null);

  document.getElementById("jsonDiv").innerHTML = localRequest.responseText;

  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(localRequest.response);

  document.getElementById("jsonParsed").innerHTML = jsonObject.computerGrid;

}
```

here is my simple function, I first display the response, and then it errors when I am trying to parse the data.
Thanks

I expect an object that I can .computerGrid or .playerGrid.

Comment: why `JSON.parse(localRequest.response)` not `JSON.parse(localRequest.responseText)` ?

Comment: Should never ever use the `async:false` option. That is a terrible practice and is deprecated by browser vendors

Comment: You have a missing quote `,"2,"2"` in the 9th or 10th array element. sure this isnt a typo error problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your json, just search by `"2,`, there are 2 occurences, it should be `"2",`.
You are missing a closing `"`.

Also, in order to the JSON to be valid, it should look like this:

```
{"playerGrid":[["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3"],["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3"],["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3"],["4","2","2","2","2","3","2","2","2","3"],["2","2","2","2","7","3","2","2","2","3"],["2","2","2","2","7","2","2","2","2","2"],["2","2","2","3","3","3","2","2","2","2"],["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"]],"computerGrid":[["2","2","2","7","4","9","9","2","2","2"],["2","9","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],["2","9","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],["2","9","2","2","9","9","2","2","2","2"],["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],["9","9","9","9","9","2","2","2","2","2"],["2","2","2","2","7","2","2","2","9","2"],["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"],["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"],["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"]]}
```

Keys, `playerGrid` and `computerGrid` must be between `"`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `JSON.parse(localRequest.responseText)`
2. Your `JSON` is incorrect, you are missing quotes around some numbers like `"2,`
3. Object Keys `"playerGrid"` and `"computerGrid"` must be quoted too

```js
let d = `{
"playerGrid": [
  ["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","3","3","3"], ["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],
  ["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3"], ["3","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","3"],
  ["4","2","2","2","2","3","2","2","2","3"], ["2","2","2","2","7","3","2","2","2","3"],
  ["2","2","2","2","7","2","2","2","2","2"], ["2","2","2","3","3","3","2","2","2","2"],
  ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"], ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"]],
"computerGrid": [
  ["2","2","2","7","4","9","9","2","2","2"], ["2","9","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"],
  ["2","9","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"], ["2","9","2","2","9","9","2","2","2","2"],
  ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2"], ["9","9","9","9","9","2","2","2","2","2"],
  ["2","2","2","2","7","2","2","2","9","2"], ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"],
  ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"], ["2","2","2","2","2","2","2","2","9","2"]]
}`;

console.log(JSON.parse(d))
```

PS: you can always validate your json with [codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator](https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator)